# How to use a wand without being noticed

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, stealth

Let's say a thief wants to use a wand stealthily. Is there any way of using a wand without being noticed? Is a stealth check sufficient? Can he activate the wand under his clothes without being seen?

I haven't seen a rule covering this.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, it is not a duplicate since casting a spell and using a magic device are 2 different actions with different rules.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it is a related question, so having the link here is still useful.

Comment: Is that an activated wand under your clothes or are you just happy to see me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the description of wands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wands) they use a [Spell Trigger method](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Spell-Trigger).

> Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from
>   a wand is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of
>   opportunity... To activate a wand, a character must hold it in hand (or whatever passes for a hand, for non-humanoid creatures) and point it in the general direction of the target or area.

Spell Trigger

> No gestures or spell finishing is needed, just a special knowledge of
>   spellcasting that an appropriate character would know, and a single
>   word that must be spoken.

So to be able to use the wand you need to

1. Point in the direction of the target.
2. Utter a single word. (*note: not a full verbal component, just one word*)

I don't know of an explicit ruling here, but that sounds like it would be a Sleight of Hand check and possibly a Stealth check to utter a word without being detected. Obviously this would be a DM call, but it seems pretty simple.

I think the more complicated question is about the targets noticing.

If you cast a Magic Missile, it will be obvious that it came from somewhere. But if you cast something like Charm Person, it becomes a question of *"do they know?"*. Are they aware that they had to make a Charm Person save? Even if you're very stealthy, there's a chance that the target of your spell figures out that something is not right.

Comment: In the case of *charm person*, those who make their saving throw are aware of "a hostile force," and that they overcame it. If they fail, and didn't see anything, then they know nothing.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think as a DM, it would be opposed skill checks at the least (sleight of hand vs perception or similarly appropriate check)

Comment: I think _"observer's Perception check"_ is implied by Sleight of Hand as it is in all of the descriptions. You would absolutely be subject to a Perception check and if you failed, likely subject to a Bluff vs. Sense Motive check to cover it up.